# Problem specifying namespace for VisualStateManager in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, assemblies

Should be simple but i can't seem to find the answer

I am trying to make a custom ControlTemplate that uses VisualStateManger.  MSDN says to include

xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"

However, it says that i am missing a reference to the assembly.  So i try to add it but can't find System.Windows assembly under the .NET tab to add it.   What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to `PresentationFramework.dll` (from [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) documentation).

You'll also need to make sure that you're targetting .NET 4.0, not 3.5sp1.  `VisualStateManager` was added to WPF in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running .net 4.5 then your reference needs to change from
http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation to
http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation